# What are the conditions to make the parfor in Matlab Parallel computing work correctly

Tags: matlab, parfor

I have a question regarding parfor. What are the conditions to achieve the best performance of a parfor loop and to make it work correctly/properly?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Parallel for-Loops (parfor)](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/distcomp/parallel-for-loops-parfor.html) in the documentation, in particular the various concepts, such as "Deciding when yo use parfor", "Programming considerations" and "Classification of variables".

Comment: Thanks. I also found this blog http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2009/10/02/using-parfor-loops-getting-up-and-running/